# The 'New File' function is not working in Textmate. Are shell variables to blame?

Tags: ruby, textmate

I can't create new files from within Textmate. I'm not sure why it's doing this or how to go about fixing it.

I recently changed the "Shell Variables" because certain functions weren't working like the "Comment Line" ⌘/, and other stuff. It would say something like

```
env: ruby: no such file or directory
```

Ruby 1.8 is installed in `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. I recently installed Ruby 1.9 through RVM, but I was just following directions and don't know where it is installed, or if it is even being used.

[image: Here is what my Shell Variables currently look like]

I don't really know much about path dependencies and such. I searched for "`ruby`" in the Finder and there are 16 folders titled "ruby" or "Ruby", but they all stem from that original path `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. What should I do to get Textmate working again? Is it something to do with where I have Ruby installed?

I followed the instructions on "[TextMate 'env: ruby: No such file or directory'](http://michaelfarmer.info/blog-101)" when trying to fix the "Comment Selection" function in TextMate.

---

UPDATE:

I just found on the "[TextMateAndThePath](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/TextMateAndThePath)" page on Textmate's help wiki that

> There can be many files named ruby on the system, but only one file can exist at the path /usr/bin/ruby

When I run `type ruby` at the command line, it returns two `/opt/local/bin/ruby` paths.
Is this what is breaking Textmate, and if so what can I do about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't create new files"? How are you creating new files? Any errors?

Comment: no errors, it just stalls, and then nothing happens. I right-click on a folder and click the "new file" option. the hotkey doesn't work either. Maybe there is some error in the background I'm not seeing?

Comment: Instead of searching for 'ruby', if you want to find where you have ruby installed, run `type ruby` in the terminal. This will tell you what's executed if you simply run `ruby`. If you want to see all copies of `ruby` in your `PATH` then run `type -a ruby`.

Comment: Also, you may want to open Console.app and see if TextMate is printing anything there when you try and create a new file.

Comment: sorry, I got the path `/opt/local/bin/ruby` from typing `type ruby` while in my Rails app PATH. Running that command in my root path though gives me `ruby is /opt/local/bin/ruby
ruby is /opt/local/bin/ruby`. Is this the problem? I'm running console right now while Textmate is whirring away after I tried to create a new file and nothing is happening. Console keeps saying `12/23/11 7:43:12 PM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mozy.backup[35062]) posix_spawn("/Applications/Mozy.app/Contents/Resources/MozyBackup", ...): No such file or directory`

Comment: AHA console gave a textmate specific output `12/23/11 7:45:12 PM TextMate[28068] runCommand:input:variables:returnCode:async: error during exit` I don't know what to make of it though

Comment: Having two rubies on your path shouldn't matter; it'll just use the first. See [this](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/textmate-rvm-activesupport-outside-of.html) and [this](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/07/textmate-and-rvm-behave.html) for two ways of setting up TextMate with RVM rupies--may or may not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new file function works now.

In Terminal, I ran the command `echo $PATH` and put the output in a "Shell Variable" in Textmate. So now my "Shell Variables" look like:

[image]

I unchecked the first `PATH` which Textmate automatically put in there, and created a new one (the last one) to reflect what the `echo $PATH` command returned for me. I got the idea from "[TextMateAndThePath](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/TextMateAndThePath)".

Don't worry if your PATH is different from theirs. Mine was really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem with my Textmate I found that the path information change for the location of the ruby file I would recomend running which ruby in terminal.

> ```
> which ruby 
>  /Users/newdark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
> ```

You then need to put that in place of the TM_RUBY value

[image]

Also I noticed that your Variable path could end up creating a path that is not longer there in my case this was true. However you don't really need the path variable when you are working with ruby on rails. Try unchecking it and try again if this does not fix it then I am out of ideas however hope this helps.